# SQL count occurrences rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this:

> **c1|c2** 
> a|       2 
> b|       1 
> a|       1 
> b|       3 
> a|       2

how count this to get result like this

> **col1|   col2|**     number of occurrences 
> a|    1|              1 
> a|    2|              2 
> b|    3|              1

And after get max value like this:

**col1****col2**

a|2

b|1

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Count 1 is your friend, count * leads to a longer load time.

```
SELECT C1, C2, COUNT(1) AS numberofoccurrences
FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY C1, C2
```

Sorry for delay. To get Max use following;

```
; WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT c1, c2, COUNT(1) AS NoOfOccurence FROM TEST
    GROUP BY c1, c2
), BTE AS(
    SELECT c1, c2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c1 ORDER BY NoOfOccurence DESC) AS RN FROM CTE
)SELECT c1, c2 FROM BTE WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: Your assertion that `count(1)` would be better than `count(*)` is incorrect; they are equivalent. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1 for a thorough discussion on the subject.

Comment: Thats work fine, thanks,
I have last questions, how get from this max value, like this 
a|2|2
b|3|1

Comment: That's funny. `count(1)` would be *slower*, wouldn't the optimizer convert it to `count(*)` internally. `count(*)` = select rows. `count(1)` = select rows, generate a 1 in every row, check whether the 1 is not null, if it isn't count it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete solution which includes the final max value output. Also note that an index on c1 and c2 will drastically improve performance.

```
-- Sample data
-- including an id for use as a tie-breaker for a unique pk/clustered index on c1 & c2
DECLARE @tbl TABLE 
  (id int identity not null, c1 char(1), c2 tinyint, primary key (c1,c2,id));
INSERT @tbl VALUES ('a', 2), ('b', 1), ('a', 1), ('b', 3), ('a', 2);

-- Solution
SELECT c1, MaxOccurs = MAX(c)
FROM
(
  SELECT c1, c2, c = COUNT(1)
  FROM @tbl
  GROUP BY c1, c2
) x
GROUP BY c1;
```